# Was this question closed by a human or a bot? what more details could be added?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886619/can-there-be-an-infinite-set-s-whose-elements-all-contain-s) was closed because `This question needs details or clarity.`

"can there be an infinite set S whose elements all contain S? [closed]"

However, the question was understood, commented by many and even answered and accepted.

Additionally, the question has TWO examples and it's a very simple statement.

What more clarity could be added?

Please help me understand how to pose more clear questions so to avoid being closed, and how to re-open the question.

Comment: The question was [closed by 5 users](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4886619/timeline).

Answer (score 12):

The question is not closed by a bot, instead it is closed by 5 users.

The question is unclear. Two users commented ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886619/can-there-be-an-infinite-set-s-whose-elements-all-contain-s#comment10424099_4886619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886619/can-there-be-an-infinite-set-s-whose-elements-all-contain-s#comment10424378_4886619)) on your post, I guess they expect you to clear their doubt. However no comments was made to answer that (They are not among the 5 users that close your question though).

Two other users give some high level comments, relating your question to set theory. One of them also answered your question, which you accepted. However, it is not clear if what they said is what you are looking for. Indeed, it is not clear from your question if you know/care what is ZFC.

Ways to clarify your post/avoid being unclear:

- Answer to people's comment.
- Provide your motivation and background. That way others could at least guess what  you are after, if the post is unclear.